# Design content query webpart with jquery

Tags: content-query-web-part

I wanna design a web part (Content query webpart) in my homepage with  jquery and i've no idea how can i do it!
This webpart retrive data from a custom list (News List).

Comment: On which SharePoint Version are you?

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you are trying to achieve, what SharePoint version you are using etc. for anyone to be able to give you a great answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not very much information from you, but you could use the SharePoint library for Javascript and get your list items.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I want to change interface of my webpart in my home page of sharepoint 2013 with jquery

Comment: could you be more specific?